# Can Friction Pendulum Bearing/System (FPB/FPS) suppresses the effect of an earthquake from every direction or only from one direction?

Tags: civil-engineering, friction, bearings, bridges, earthquake-engineering

Can Friction Pendulum Bearing (FPB) AKA. Friction Pendulum System (FPS) suppresses the effect of an earthquake from every direction or only from one direction?

Please take a look at the tests which seem to be made from only one direction. [Tectonic hazards/Shake-table](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Tectonic_hazards/Shake-table)

Comment: How have you analyzed the inputs and outputs of this system?

Comment: @SolarMike Please check my edit

Comment: Why do you say that when your linked page says a shake table generates vibrations in all 6 axes?    What we need is a good explanation of a FPBS and its intended capability.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [article](https://www.earthquakeprotection.com/triple-pendulum) about triple-PDB systems which has some nice diagrams of each level within the system.  From one of the pictures, it seems clear that the  circumferential symmetry means a PDB handles vibrations in at the very least all axes in the plane.
[image]

from the article,

> The Triple Pendulum™ isolator's inner pendulum consists of an inner
> slider that slides along two inner concave spherical surfaces.
> Properties of the inner pendulum are typically chosen to reduce the
> peak accelerations acting on the isolated structure and its contents,
> to minimize the participation of higher structure modes, and to reduce
> structure shear forces that occur during service level earthquakes.